# Mstest and access to ApplicationData.Current

Tags: uwp, mstest

I am using MsTest.exe for running a unit test project. The problem here is that the main project store data in files inside LocalStorage, if I run tests using Visual Studio everything works fine. If I try to work from command line, I get exception:

```
The process has no package identity.(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)
```

each time I try to access some file inside LocalStorage :

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using a "Unit Test App (Windows Universal)" project for this, or a generic test project? The former is the correct one!

Comment: I am using Unit Test App(Windows Universal) like I said in visual studio everything run as expected but from command line I get that exception, the reason (I think) is that no app is launched when I run from command line, instead when I run from VS I see an app running, with some textblock that says tests are running.

Comment: Any update on this? Feedback is highly appreciated :)